# adding windows explorer type functionality to my program

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-3.5

Is there a .net control I can use which will allow me to create a program which allows me to browsers through drives and folders to open any given file in the associated program and start any program?

Would OpenFileDialog do this, or is there a windows explorer type control I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no control. However:

- Using `Process.Start` on a filename will automatically open it with the default handler.
- You can enable people to open it with another program by passing it as arguments to the program, at least, usually.
- You can use the `IO.DirectoryInfo` and `IO.FileInfo` types to retrieve the directory structure.
- You can use `TreeView`s and `ListView`s to emulate Explorer's controls.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a reason to use it, so I can't make a recommendation, but I've had my eye on [this one](http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm) for awhile. It looks pretty good.

HTH